# How can I really see what font the element is using?

Tags: css, firebug

When I look on the font-family of an HTML element (from js, firebug or similar) it's always a list. How can I see which of the font is actually used from the list?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think Browser searches from left to right and uses first found font. Perhaps, I am wrong and would like to know the answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Font Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/) add-on for Firefox can do this. Since it’s clearly possible, it sure would be convenient if this were built in to Firebug.

[image: Font Finder window]

---

**Update 2012/2/4:**

I examined the Font Finder source to find out how it works, and it’s actually a clever little hack. The relevant code is in the [Detector class](https://github.com/bendodson/Font-Finder/blob/master/Firefox/chrome/content/fontfinder.js#L405) in *fontfinder.js*. To quote the source:

> Inner class that's used to determine which font is rendered. It
>   operates under the foundation that each font has a unique height &
>   width when given a large enough font size & sample string

What’s it doing is almost like an automated version of [Marcel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5974389/27581).
So how it works is that a dummy element — with the text “mmmmmmmmmmlil” — is added to the DOM. It is set to use the browser fallback font, “serif”, at a font-size of 72px. With that, Font Finder knows the width and height of the element when the fallback font is in use. Next, it just iterates through all the fonts listed in the `font-family`, setting the font on the element in turn, for each one in the list. If the width and height of the element matches the width and height when the fallback font was set, we can deduce that the given font is not present. The first font in the list which produces a different width or height on the element will be the font that is actually being rendered (note: there is a special case involved when the fallback font, “serif,” is in the `font-family` list).

There is also a Chrome version of Font Finder. It differs ([relevant source](https://github.com/bendodson/Font-Finder/blob/master/Chrome/selection.js#L156)) in that the browser fallback font appears to be “sans” — not “serif.” Any code using this method will have to have browser-specific knowledge of the fallback font.

Comment: It would be interesting to see that feature in Firebug. I wonder how they find the current font? Is there an API for that or is it possible from JavaScript? I know you might not know the answer, but I just posted it here in case someone else know. Thanks.

Comment: @grm Since I too was curious, I took a look. I’ve updated the answer with what I found.

Comment: thanks for your help :) Very interesting! I changed your solution to the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

I realise it's not ideal, but you can copy the text from the viewport and paste it into a rich text editor, and it will tell you.

Comment: That's a neat trick, would loved it though if firebug would have been able to show it too...

Comment: Yeah, it feels like there should be a better way. :)

Comment: @alex: Well, you *could* always grab FF code and step through the font rendering code.. That *would* be a better way ;)

Comment: @Damian I considered that, but the copy and check would be quicker.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit fiddly, but using Firebug you can tweak the name of each font in a font-family, working left to right until the element's font changes, meaning it was the last font you changed is being used. On the latest Firebug at least, you only need to add or remove a letter from a font's name for the change to be reflected.